# How to edit a raster band

Tags: qgis, raster

I am working with several raster layers for which I need to do a post-processing analysis to compare land use over several years. However the raster I am using have over 40 different land use classifications while I am only focussing on one or two. Is there any way to remove these classifications from the bands? I have tried the tool "rearrange bands". It didn't give me an option to remove anything, but perhaps I am doing something wrong. I am using QGIS 3.22 białowieża.

Comment: If you have done a classification then there should only be one band that contains a range of values from 1-40. You can use the [raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) to create a new raster layer that "filters" out the desired values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

1. Use raster calculator to "filter" out the classification values you want to use.

```
IF(("classification@1" = 1 OR "classification@1" = 2), "classification@1", -999999)

    a. "classification" = the layer

    b. @1 = band 1

    c. If raster equal 1 or 2, then set value to it's self, otherwise set to some other value.
```

[image]

2. You can redefine your NaN values if you don't want them. You can use GRASS r.null tool

[image]

FIANL OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Hi Binx, thanks a lot! I got exactly what I wanted, now onto my land use and land cover analysis